# Python Telegram bot - second InLineKeyboard not working

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I made  telegram bot which works fine except the second InLineKeyboard (keyboard2 in the relevant code below). Can you provide any hints why? Thanks!

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "start":
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1", callback_data="1")

    ...

    btn10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="10", callback_data="10")

    keyboard.row(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5)
    keyboard.row(btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10)

    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, "some text", reply_markup=keyboard)
else:
    keyboard2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Yes", callback_data="yes")
    btn12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="No", callback_data="no")
    keyboard2.add(btn11, btn12)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "some text", reply_markup=keyboard2)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
 if call.message:
    if call.data == "1":
        img = open('1.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, photo=img, reply_markup=keyboard)
        img.close()

    #Nine more buttons here

    elif call.data == "yes":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "some text", reply_markup=keyboard)
    elif call.data == "no": 
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "some text")
```

Comment: Could you explain better what's the problem happening and whats the part of the code is giving you the error?

Comment: Which library are you using?